# Custom Menu Form Node Creation

Tags: nodes, forms, routes

I have been going over posts and examples for hours but finally need specific help on where my code is broken. I'm trying to create link in navigation that opens a form to create a new node. However no link anywhere is being made and I'm not sure what is missing. While its supposed to also upload a image I'm not worried right now since it doesn't work anyway. As a beginner my module looks correct but experienced eyes can hopefully give me some advice on where I went wrong! Thanks for any support and let me know of anything else I can add to solve this problem.

```
<?php

function ImageLoader_menu() { 
$items = array();
$items['ImageLoader'] = array(
   'title' => 'Image Uploader',
   'description' => t('Upload a image.'),
   'page callback' => 'ImageLoader_upload_form_submit',
   'page arguments' => array('ImageLoader_upload_form'),
   'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    );
  return $items;
}

function ImageLoader_upload_form() {
$form = array();

$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Name'
);

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Create Node!'
);
return $form;
}

function ImageLoader_upload_form_submit($form, $form_state){
$node = new stdClass();
$node -> type = 'Nature';
$node -> title = $form_state['values']['name'];
$node -> language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->path = array('alias' => '/'); 
node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.
$node->uid = 200;

$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);

drupal_set_message(t('Node Created'));
}
```

Comment: first of all `ImageLoader` should be in lowercase format `imageLoader`

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code in your code and clear the cache.

```
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
```